# passing parameters from webpage to powerapps

Tags: powerapps, url-parameters

final-values?data=0&data=0&data=0....actually I want to send the values that I am receiving in the URL to my PowerApps project and I want to store those values in an array variable and access them when needed

Comment: you have to add some more info, like your powerapps is a canvas app or custom page or model driven app? from where are you calling your powerapps? Is it embedded or is it a link to your powerapps?

Answer (score 0):

This should be doable with a bit of split logic.
we first take the info passed into the app

```
Set(gblFinalValues,Param(final-values));
```

Then we want to split the string and save the values into a collection

```
ClearCollect(colFinalValues, Split(gblFinalValues,'&'))
```

Or a More succinct way to combine the steps

```
ClearCollect(colFinalValues, Split(Param(final-values),'&'))
```

All you should need to change for the above is the value you wish to split your array on, and the naming convention of the parameter your passing into your app.